# When i added translation to english in my app,i cant find it using english keywords

Tags: android, google-play, google-translation-api

I added String translations to my app, then switched Google Play Store to English.
When I search for my app using the English keywords, it doesn't appear at all. But when I switch my **phone** to English, the app shows up it in English.

What's the deal here?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps its Googles Dynamic Delivery

https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/dynamic-delivery

> Google Play’s app serving model, called Dynamic Delivery, uses Android App Bundles to generate and serve optimized APKs for each user’s device configuration, so users download only the code and resources they need to run your app.

...

> For example, one split APK may include the code and resources for an additional feature that only a few of your users need, **while another split APK includes resources for only a specific language** or screen density. Each of these split APKs is downloaded and installed when the user requests it or it’s required by the device.

[image]

Comment: @BataKos If you found this helpful pls remember to upvote or mark it as answered https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 0):

It was just Google Play 
I contacted them and now it all works fine